# Why is decoded json nil using Codable?

Tags: json, swift

I'm using latest version of Swift with xcode 10.1. I'm able to encode json from an object fine but decoding a json string back to an object is producing nil.

This is from a hacker noon tutorial and the tutorial source prints nil as well.

Here is the sample object:

```
class Car: NSObject, Codable {
    var name: String = ""
    var companyURL: URL? = nil
    var yearOfManufacture: Int = 0
    var isNew:Bool = true
    var otherDetailsData: [String:String]? = nil
    var carType: CarType = .Unknown
    var carSize: CarSize = CarSize(height: 0, length: 0)
}
struct CarSize: Codable {
    var height: Double
    var length: Double
}

enum CarType: String, Codable {
    case Unknown
    case SUV
    case Sedan
}

//here is sample json
        let jsonString = """
                        {
                            "name":"City ZX",
                            "isNew":true,
                            "yearOfManufacture":2018,
                            "companyURL":"www.honda.com",
                            "carType":"Sedan",
                            "carSize":{
                                       "height":200,
                                       "height":100
                                   },
                            "otherDetailsData":{
                                       "color":"Red",
                                       "fuelType":"Petrol"
                                   },
                        }
                        """
//here is where i attempt to create the object from the json string:
        if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
        {
            //And here you get the Car object back
            let carTest = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Car.self, from: jsonData)
            print("carObject currently printing nil ", carTest)
        }
```

Comment: Because the decoding fails already. Don't `try?`, `catch` the error and print it. And a dictionary with two `height` keys is invalid anyway.

Comment: error  keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "length", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "carSize", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"length\", intValue: nil) (\"length\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: ok, thanks for error tip. now i need to figure out what is going with the keyNotFound stuff.

Comment: **Read** the error message and the JSON. Is there a key `length` in the `carSize` dictionary?

Comment: @vadian You are wrong, that JSON is valid even if two keys are the same. When decoded, usually the last key will be used.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, the JSON (string) is valid but a **dictionary** cannot have two keys with the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CarSize` struct has properites `height` and `length`, but in your `jsonString` you declared just `height` twice, so you forgot to `length` which is required for decoding too.

You probably wanted to use `length` instead of second `height` in your `jsonString`

```
"carSize":{                             
    "height":200,
    "length":100
}
```

or (if your car isn't skyscraper)

```
"carSize":{                             
    "height":100,
    "length":200
}
```